# Post-Install adding files to avoid the .MSI AutoRepair feature

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

I am unsure how to phrase the title - which may be incorrect - so I will attempt to elaborate here.

**The problem:** .MSI installer auto repairs missing files (images) after manually deleting them from the directory.

**What I want:** I need my application to install a bunch of icons into the directory. These icons are considered "default" Icons and the user can, if they want, remove them from the directory. When the user removes them from the directory, I don't want the .MSI installer to "Auto Repair" them back into the directory.

I am not sure the best way to handle this situation. Any programming advice will be taken seriously.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the ComponentId to null https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007(VS.85).aspx